# TikZ: Text becomes invisible in large PDF

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I am attempting to create a family tree in TikZ, containing an excessive number of nodes. Given the fact that everything should be visible, it is currently 9 layers high and around 70 layers wide.

Increasing the width to 71 layers results in **everything** being **invisible**! One can still mark and copy the content, but not see it.

I tried to cover the problem in a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[fill=black, minimum height = 30cm, minimum width=10cm] (A) at (0, 0){};

\node[fill=black, minimum height = 30cm, minimum width=10cm] (B) at (490,0){};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This example should create a PDF with two black boxes in the left / right side. Increasing the x component of the second box from 490 to 500 results in both boxes being invisible.

I am using TeXnicCenter 2.0 with the `LaTeX -> PDF` setting and pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9). The compilation does not print any errors (such as *Dimension too large*), but the problem is not reproducable on some machines (however, I could reproduce it on three machines with the above configurations). What could cause this problem? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you nesting nodes?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) In addition to percusse's comment: Why are you nesting `tikzpicture`s?

Comment: In order to resize the ? in the boxes, I used the [scale=x] option of TikZ pictures, because the Huge-font was simply not huge enough. I read that's how you achieve that...

The procedure is: At a given node, draw a frame with a grey field in it (achieved by the second node) and additionally a large ? (achieved by the third node) with optional text below the gray field (this short example contains none). If there's any better way, I'm open for suggestions!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue; using either 503.5 or 513.5 displays the content in the boxes as expected.

Comment: The `scale=x` option does not scale font sizes. The resizing of the question marks in your example is done by the `\resizebox`es, which may as well be in the top-level node; the effect is the same there.

Comment: It's strange that you cannot reproduce the issue, but I expected as much... maybe it depends on the exact pdftex version? I use pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9).

Maybe it has to do with the coordinate margin of 512 being "breached"...

Comment: @PaulGessler Good point. I have no idea what I was doing. Sorry for that. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: The maximum distance in cm for (La)TeX (and TikZ) is  575.83174cm (16383.99997 pt). But, here, it's not your problem...

Comment: Damn, I thought the maximum distance was 16383.9x cm... But this being in pt greatly reduces the space I'm able to work in. I guess until this mystery has been solved, I'll have to just reduce the coordinate sizes and adapt the rest accordingly. Thanks for clarifying the distances!

Comment: @Brokenmind, I'm on MiKTeX 2.9 x64 (pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14). I think this is a viewer issue, do you use Adobe Reader by chance? On my system, the boxes display in SumatraPDF and Google Chrome but not in Adobe Reader.

Comment: Indeed I use Adobe Reader, but given the fact that it is very widely used, I cannot risk a display bug in the PDF and simply rely on other viewers. Very strange...

Comment: @Brokenmind, you can @-mention others in comments (as I have done here for you) to notify them of your comment. What do you think the status of this question should be? I think it now becomes off-topic for this site because it is not a TeX issue but a viewer issue.

Comment: @PaulGessler you're right, I should change it to something like "solved" or "postponed", but I don't know how to set/change a question's status (apart from marking a valid answer) or which possible states to choose from. Could you tell me?

Comment: @Brokenmind, at the bottom of the question, to the left of your username, you should see links called "close" and "delete". You can choose any of the close reasons (I think off-topic is the most appropriate here) or delete your question voluntarily. The choice is yours. `:-)`